# Not able to execute commands inside docker container[Jenkins Pipeline]

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Image is successfully getting built during docker.build() step
While trying to execute ls inside the container, it executes in workspace itself

**I want to execute some commands inside the container after "ls"**

```
node() {
def dev_image = "image_name"
def DOCKER_BRANCH = "dev"
def registry = "maven" //getting from github repo

stage("Build Image") {
    dir(app_checkout_dir) {

        // Builds Required Docker Image

           customImage = docker.build("${dev_image}/${DOCKER_BRANCH}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", "${registry}")
            customImage.inside(){
                sh "ls"

            }                
        }
```

}

Comment: Jenkins uses a large set of Docker options to mount the workspace directory into the container; you'll see these in the build log.  `sh "ls"` in fact runs inside the container, but works on the workspace directory.  Have you tried running other commands; do you have a specific reason to believe you're not in the container here?

Comment: Yes as you said I guess its running inside container...build log shows commands run between docker top  and docker stop...Kindly confirm it